# Reading a fwf with carriage returns within records

Tags: r

I am using read_fwf to read in a very large table, using a key that defines column widths and column names.  Each record in the source table contains the same number of characters, but some of the records contain carriage returns before the end of the line. Instead of counting the carriage return as a single character within the record, read_fwf treats it as the end of the record, and everything after the carriage return is read in as a separate record.

How can I read in my data without these records being split into separate rows?

```
r1 <- readr::read_fwf(efiles[1],locale = readr::locale(encoding = latin1"),col_positions = col_positions) #col_positions is the key with column widths and names
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, DanT! Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Here is the line of code in question. The files come from https://s3.amazonaws.com/rcrainfo-ftp/Production/2019-08-15T14-13-44-0400/eManifest/EM.zip. col_positions is the key with column widths and names.
 r1 <- readr::read_fwf(efiles[1],locale = readr::locale(encoding = latin1"),col_positions = col_positions)

Comment: DanT, links often go stale, and when they do this question (and any answer) becomes unreproducible. It helps incredibly to have sample data in the question itself, and it sounds like you can reduce it to just a few rows of data to demonstrate the variability you are talking about. Also, code should go in the question itself (in a [code-block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)), as comments are often missed and can be hidden if there are a lot of comments.